# Changes to interface-only Typescript files do not trigger recompile

Tags: reactjs, typescript, babeljs

I have one file, 'types.ts' that only exports interfaces such as:

```
export interface A {
}

export interface B {
}
```

These interfaces are then imported by other files. When I make changes to this file, it does not trigger the project to be recompiled.

I've gleaned that this is because typescript interface-only files don't emit anything when transpiled, thus there are no changes for Webpack to recompile. My question is: does anyone know if there is any way around this? I want any changes to 'types.ts' to trigger the project to be recompiled regardless of whether it only contains definitions or not.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? It won't change anything on runtime. A static TypeScript check should be re-run on these file changes though.

Comment: When the project fails to compile (lets say because of a faulty interface definition), the expected behaviour is that after I fix those errors, the file will then re-compile on save. 

Although the typescript compiler will not actually emit anything from the interface-only file, it still needs to initially infer the types in order to do its job properly.

Comment: @elimist3 Did you find an answer?